Prove the interior of a finite intersection of sets is equal to the finite intersection of interiors
The task is to prove $(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i)^{\circ} = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i^{\circ}$. A follow up question is does this condition hold if we take countable unions?
My idea is to show that the two sides of the equation are subsets of each other. $(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i)^{\circ} \subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i^{\circ}$: Let x be in $(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i)^{\circ}$. Then there exists an epsilon "e" neighborhood B(e,x) contained in $(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i)$. So for each $A_i$, B(e,x) is contained in $A_i$, thus x is in every $A_i^{\circ}$, as desired.
Now let y be in $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i^{\circ}$. Then y is in the interior of each $A_i$. For each $A_i$ there is an $\epsilon_i$ such that $B(\epsilon_i, y)$ is contained in $A_i$. Let $\epsilon = min\left\{\epsilon_i, 1 < i < n+1\right \}$ Then $B(\epsilon,y)$ is contained in $(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i)$. Thus y is in $(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i)^{\circ}$.  We are done.
For the countable case, since A_i are all open, and since the arbitrary intersection of open sets isn't necessarily open, it seems that the statement wouldn't hold. However, I am having trouble finding a counterexample for this.
Is my reasoning valid? Any help/tips would be appreciated.

If this  is a question in general topology (as your tag says) then the proof is wrong.

I changed the tag. If we are in the standard topology on R, is the proof still wrong?

If you work in metric spaces (which I assume) then your proof is correct. For countable intersections this is indeed false. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$ consider $A_n==(-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n})$. Then $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n^{\circ}=[0,1]$ is not an open set, and so cannot be equal to the interior of anything.
